# Api is not working in React Native with Airtel cellular data but working perfectly with other cellular data and wifi on (Android)

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

Hi everyone I am working on React Native app it is almost done everything working great but when I want to access the app with my Airtel cellular data it is not working  .I dont know why I am getting this issue .
following is my Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: you don't have the permisson

Comment: can you please more elaborate.  What i  did I swaped the network type lte to 3g then 3g to lte and it worked but question is what was the issue?